# What is the best way to enhance query performance for a large database?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, bigdata, amazon-rds, amazon-athena

I'm working on an **RDS MariaDB** database which contains more than **270 highly-connected tables** with more than **10 million records**. The main goal is to **enhance queries performance**, the most important **queries are very complex** and I need a solution that handles these queries more effectively.
The following is a query that generates the result in **6 minutes**!!

```
SELECT table1.col1  AS col1,
   table1.col2      AS col2,
   table2.col1      AS country,
   table3.col1      AS col1,
   table2.col1      AS col1,
   table3.col2      AS time,
   Concat_ws('; ', Collect_set(DISTINCT table4.col1)) AS Route,
   CASE
     WHEN table5.col1 IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
     ELSE table5.col1
   end              AS MAH,
   CASE
     WHEN table6.col1 IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
     ELSE table6.col1
   end              AS MFG,
   table7.col1      AS PackSize,
   table1.col3      AS col3
FROM   table3
   INNER JOIN table7
           ON table3.col3 = table7.col1
   INNER JOIN table8
           ON table3.col4 =
              table8.col4
   INNER JOIN table2
           ON table8.col4 = table2.col1
   LEFT JOIN table9 AS table5
          ON table3.col5 = table5.col1
   LEFT JOIN table9 AS table6
          ON table3.col6 = table6.col1
   INNER JOIN table10
           ON table3.col3 =
              table10.col1
   INNER JOIN table4
           ON table10.col2 = table4.col1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT table11.col1                  AS
                               col3,
                               table12.col1 AS
          DosageUnit_col1,
                               table13.col1             AS
          col1,
                               table13.col2                AS
                               col2
               FROM   table7
                      INNER JOIN table11
                              ON table7.col2 =
                                 table11.col1
                      INNER JOIN table14
                              ON table7.col1 =
                                 table14.col1
                      INNER JOIN table12
                              ON table14.col1 =
                                 table12.col1
                      INNER JOIN (SELECT table15.col1
                                         AS
                                         col1,
                                         Concat_ws(' / ', Collect_set(
                                         table16.col1)) AS
                              col1,
                                         Concat_ws('/', Collect_set(
                                         table17.col2,
                                         table18.col1))
                                         AS
                              col2
                                  FROM   table15
                                         INNER JOIN table17
                                                 ON table15.col1 =
table17.col3
INNER JOIN table18
ON
table17.col1 =
table18.col1
INNER JOIN table16
ON table17.col4 =
table16.col1
GROUP  BY table15.col1) AS
table13
ON table12.col2 =
table13.col1
GROUP  BY dosageunit_col1) AS table1
ON table7.col1 = table1.dosageunit_col1
WHERE  table3.col3 IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?) and `market_authorizations`.`authority_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
   AND table3.col4 IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
   AND table3.mapped_col1 IS NULL
   AND col2 >= ''
GROUP  BY table3.col1
ORDER  BY table3.col2 DESC;
```

The first idea I thought about is to migrate the data to **Amazon Redshift**, so I created a migration task using AWS DMS to export all data from RDS **to S3 in Apache Parquet format** to take advantage of the **columnar storage** and **compression**.
The migration task created **a parquet file for each exported table**.
To test the performance of the various options to use in the solution (RDS, Redshift, Redshift Spectrum, Athena), I used the following query which returns **the first million records of a table**:

```
select * from table limit 1000000;
```

and the execution time in seconds was as follows:

- RDS MariaDB (8 CPU, 32 RAM, 600 IOPS) => **23.462 sec**
- Redshift Spectrum (Two nodes, each node is with 2 CPUs, 15 RAM) => **23 sec**
- Athena => **4.01 sec**

Although Athena and Redshift spectrum read from the **same file stored in S3**, the performance between both is **significantly different**.

Why the performance **didn't get better** at all when we used **Redshift Spectrum**?

Why do Redshift and RDS have **the same performance**?

Why I have got the same performance exactly (23 sec) when **I resized** the Redshift cluster **from one node into two nodes**?

Is that because I use **unpartitioned data** (one parquet file for each table)?

Why does **Athena have the best performance** even though it reads from the same source as the Redshift Spectrum?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the query plan in MariaDB and working out how to optimise your query there before migrating to other DBMSs, which is just moving or changing the problem - it's not solving anything because you don't actually understand the underlying root causes of your performance issues

Comment: The way to get better performance is to allow the query engine to parallel the work. It depends also on the query and the data. The query engine of Athena is often better in planning queries for parallel processing, and the service is using many nodes by default for most queries, unlike Redshift and RDS where you provision the notes.

Comment: I expect you are simply measuring the amount of time it takes to present 1M rows back to you bench.  Athena has a web interface and likely is using some cursor behavior by default so it is fast in presenting the first N rows.  If you want to measure the DB scan speed I'd change the LIMIT to 10 but add an ORDER BY.  This way all the data has to be read but only a small amount presented to you.

Comment: @NickW Yes, it's one of the problems, I didn't work on the database before and didn't go deep into the schema and queries. The schema and query plan should be enhanced, but I need to know why the performance didn't get better when using columnar storage in S3 and Redshift Spectrum for a simple query like (select * from table)??

Comment: @Guy But what if we want to use Redshift in our application, not Athena? what should I do to make it work in parallel? Please note that increasing the nodes number didn't make any performance enhancement at all!!

Comment: @ObadaQafisheh why did you think that moving to a solution that used columnar storage would improve the performance of a query like  (select * from table)? The point I was trying to make in my first comment was that if you don't understand the problem in your existing system how are you going to identify alternatives that may solve the issue - especially if you also don't understand the uses cases that may perform better (or worse) on the alternatives you are looking at?

Comment: If you don't change the SQL engine (Redshift) and don't change the data files, you have to change the query. As mentioned `select *` can't be improved much, and you need to specify exactly what you want (columns, functions, joins, windows, conditions, aggregations...) and then optimize the query. Check the output of `EXPLAIN` for hints.